# How do I get list of all possible tickers (and also maybe their meanings) for various dataset libraries?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

so the way I usually get some dataset (in this example, US Product Price Index) from econdb library is this:

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pylab as plt
start=datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end=datetime.datetime(2021,12,31)
df = pdr.DataReader('ticker=PPIUS','econdb',start,end)
```

Is there any way I could view all the possible tickers (ticker=) without going to econdb.com and just by viewing some list on Python? I have the same question for World Bank database.

Answer (score 1):

For Econdb, there is a separate api call to get all sources, but `pandas_datareader` does not support it (at least I could not find it in the source). You may look into [inquisitor](https://github.com/econdb/inquisitor), which has a specific call to get the sources.

For the World Bank, `pandas_datareader` has methods to get the sources. Use `pandas_datareader.wb.get_indicators()` or `search()`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this option is not available (you would need to find the tickers on the web, for instance, on https://www.econdb.com/tree/sections/ or https://www.econdb.com/main-indicators or in the search form). We will add a parameter to list tickers by search string in the API, and hopefully it is ready in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

@hkm

You can now use the `search` parameter to find series through the API.

```
import requests
query = 'united states'
requests.get('https://www.econdb.com/api/series/?search=%s&format=json&expand=meta' % query).json()['results']
```

At the moment, the pandas_datareader module is failing for such queries, we will soon submit a code revision to include this functionality.